# Probability that favorite will win

Tags: probability

Two people compete in a game. What is the probability that the favored person wins?

The probability $p$ that person A beats person B is chosen continuously uniformly randomly $U(0,1)$.

Favored person of the two is the one that has a probability of winning the game greater than $0.5$.

---

My intuition is that the answer is $0.75$, an average between $0.5$ and $1$.

I tried looking at it geometrically by drawing a unit square and a diagonal. Each horizontal segment represents one sample from the uniform distribution, and the intersection with the diagonal splits $p$ and $1-p$ region. Now, draw a horizontal line crossing the center of the square. Then the answer to the question should be the $\color{blue}{\text{area where A is favored}}$ plus $\color{red}{\text{the area where B is favored}}$, over the area of the square.

[image]

This turns out to be $6/8$ (due to congruent triangles), which is $0.75$ as my intuition suspected.

---

I have two questions.

1. Is my geometrical reasoning a valid and acceptable solution?
2. How would you formally and rigorously solve this problem? A solution that would be easier to generalize to other distributions and other definitions of a "favored" person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the rv 'probability that A beats B' denoted as $X_1 \sim U[0,1]$ and the rv 'A beats B' $X_2\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(X_1)$. Then:
$$P(X_2=1|\sigma(X_1))(\omega)=X_1(\omega)$$
$$\begin{aligned}P(\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1 > 0.5\}|\sigma(X_1))(\omega)&=E[\mathbb{I}_{\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1 > 0.5\}}|\sigma(X_1)](\omega)=\\&=\mathbb{I}_{\{X_1 > 0.5\}}E[\mathbb{I}_{\{X_2=1\}}|\sigma(X_1)](\omega)=\\
&=\mathbb{I}_{\{X_1 > 0.5\}}X_1(\omega)\\
P(\{X_2=0\}\cap \{X_1 \leq 0.5\}|\sigma(X_1))(\omega)
&=\mathbb{I}_{\{X_1 \leq 0.5\}}(1-X_1(\omega))\\
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore
$$P((\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1 > 0.5\})\cup(\{X_2=0\}\cap \{X_1 \leq 0.5\}))=\\
=E[P((\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1 > 0.5\})\cup(\{X_2=0\}\cap \{X_1 \leq 0.5\})|\sigma(X_1))]=\\
=E[P(\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1 > 0.5\}|\sigma(X_1))]+E[P(\{X_2=0\}\cap \{X_1 \leq 0.5\}|\sigma(X_1))]$$
and
$$E[P(\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1 > 0.5\}|\sigma(X_1))]=\int_{[0.5,1]}xdx=\frac{1}{2}(1-0.25)=\frac{0.75}{2}$$
$$E[P(\{X_2=0\}\cap \{X_1 \leq 0.5\}|\sigma(X_1))]=\int_{[0,0.5]}(1-x)dx=0.5-\frac{0.25}{2}=\frac{0.75}{2}$$
The result is $0.75$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I generally wait a bit before accepting an answer. (I upvoted it, I don't know why someone would downvote.)

Answer (score -1):

Given $p$, the probability that the favored person wins is $p$ if $p>1/2$ and $1-p$ if $p<1/2$.

$P(\text{favored person wins}) = \int_p P(\text{favored person wins} | p)f(p)dp$

Note that $f(p)=1 \; \forall \; p$.

$P(\text{favored person wins}) = \int_{0}^{1/2} (1-p)dp + \int_{1/2}^{1} pdp = 3/4$

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is an error please point it out so I can fix it.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I don't downvote answers), but I also didn't upvote (this appears to be a less rigorous version of the previous answer).

Comment: Thanks. The previous answer is unnecessarily tedious. I wonder one could reach out to the downvoters on this forum to understand the underlying reason.